# Maintaining white space in html select tag

Tags: php, html

I have a list of strings that I would like to display in a HTML select object. The strings look something like :

id - name - description

I would like the fields to align however. In PHP I'm using

```
sprintf ("%4s%10s%20s", $id, $name, $description);
```

which works fine. The problem is the multiple spaces is compacted to 1 space in the select list. I tried using the pre and white-space CSS properties of the select box, but it has no effect. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use `&nbsp;` instead, they are non-breaking spaces so it won't collapse.

You could do:

```
str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", sprintf("%4s%10s%20s", $id, $name, $description));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS to set the font of the options to a monospaced font. Use `&nbsp;` instead of spaces (you can use str_pad() instead of sprintf()).

https://www.php.net/str_pad

Comment: I was using monospaced fonts. Your solution works too, but I preferred the single str_replace to 3 str_pad's.

Answer (score 0):

Replace spaces with &nbsp; HTML entity.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to replace the spaces with `&nbsp;` to make this work correctly; though part of me thinks there's a much better to do this but my HTML-fu is weak...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in the html "code" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the multiple spaces following each other with non breaking spaces:

```
&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert spaces to `&nbsp;`?

Try to use `&nbsp;` (Non breaking space) is that what your looking for?